# Microservice deployment --- simple jars vs docker containers

Tags: java, docker, war, microservices, continuous-deployment

I am about to deploy a set of JAVA based microservices.
I am confused as to whether:

1. Run them as simple jars via "java -jar [JAR_NAME]"
2. Run them in a JAVA based docker container.
3. Run them as a war.

Please offer me pros and cons of each implementation as this will save me a lot of headache if I use the suggested best approach :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: definitely  docker

Comment: This is an opinion based question / answer. The pros / cons will be different for everyone so it is difficult to answer.

Comment: What if I use the jar approach? Will I be aloof of the advantages offered by Docker then? What if I need to scale my application? Will the jar allow me as smoothly as docker does? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 4):

Definitely Docker. Using containerization gives you max flexibility.

In your first approach, you jar is dependent on Java. Whenever you create new VM, you need to install fix set of software to support you application.

Benefits in second approach,

**First, everything is going to be in single container.**

You can install all required software in container and that container can be user in any VM. You have flexibility to use java of your choice for each microservices. Only install docker and everything is going to be worked.

**Second, Dev Prod Parity**

If you thing very much of microservice architecture and [12-factor](https://12factor.net/) apps. Then docker helps to support lots of factors. 
Your java and other software are going to be unique in all your environment. That means you are never going to get surprise whether it is working in QA and not in Prod due to some version mismatch of runtime environment.

**Third, Flexibility**

If you go into microservice architecture, then why only java. You can also go with GO, Python or other languages. At this time, rather installing runtime environment for each platform on each VM it is very useful to have microservice in containers.

**Last, Deployment Easiness**

You can use docker-compose or docker swarm to run 100s of mivroservice in single command.